# vscode shows no function documentation for some functions on hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

I guess vscode is supposed to show the full function documentation in the docstring on hovering over it. At least that is what it does for many functions. However, for some functions it only shows the function with all arguments. For example, the first link shows an example where the full docstring is displayed and the second link an example where it isnt. Both functions are from the same package, so this really does not make any sense to me. Does anyone know if there is a fix or if this is a bug that somehow has to be fixed by vscode or something?

[image: Image of working example]

[image: Image of non-working example]

Comment: Are you sure the docstring is not just shorter? It *is* displaying a docstring still.

Comment: No, it is not displaying the docstring. I noticed similar behavior for other functions as well. Both functions are in this module: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/container.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, but I found a somewhat okay-ish solution, although it's a pain.

- Settings -> Search "Python Extra Paths"
- Python › Auto Complete: Extra Paths
- Click "Edit in settings.json"
- Add this:

```
{

    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "./venv/*"
    ],
    "python.analysis.include": [
        "./*"
    ],
    "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        {
            "name": "sklearn",
            "depth": 2,
            "includeAllSymbols": true
        }
    ],
    "python.analysis.indexing": true,
    "python.analysis.gotoDefinitionInStringLiteral": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "vsintellicode.python.completionsEnabled": true,
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./venv/*"
    ],
    "python.editor.definitionLinkOpensInPeek": true,
    "python.editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,
    "python.venvPath": "./venv"
}
```

Those are the pieces I added, I'm not sure which one exactly helped, or if all of them helped. You might have to be more specific on the extra paths.

Essentially:

1. Either your third-party packages aren't getting indexed
2. They are getting indexed partially, but the depth isn't large enough to encompass the entire package.
3. Peeking, listing, and indexing are off completely
4. You don't have a virtual environment associated with your workspace.